# How can I read values in my Firebase database using swift and then make annotations on a map?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am a starter at swift and Xcode and just need some help with my code. I have made a firebase database:
[image: firebase database]

And I have changed the rules:
[image: Firebase rules]

I have a map view and have coded each annotation on the map and just need someone to show me how to read all of the locations in the database and then put them as annotations on the map view. This is all of my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsUserLocation = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        map.mapType = .satellite
        self.map.isZoomEnabled = false

        map.showsCompass = false

        map.isRotateEnabled = false
        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 51.743370
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -2.279179

        let lanDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: lanDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, span: span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "School House"
        annotation.subtitle = "Main School Building"
        annotation.coordinate = coordinates
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        map.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
        let annotationCollingwood = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotationCollingwood.title = "Collingwood"
        annotationCollingwood.subtitle = "Day House"
        annotationCollingwood.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:                                           51.742688, longitude: -2.279362)
        map.addAnnotation(annotationCollingwood)

        let annotationSibly = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotationSibly.title = "Sibly"
        annotationSibly.subtitle = "Musical Theatre"
        annotationSibly.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.743518, longitude: -2.279796)
        map.addAnnotation(annotationSibly)

        map.camera.altitude = 300.00
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func menuButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your tried with firebase.

Comment: Joe - decide what you want to ask, and ask that.  Is your problem about storing data in Firebase, retrieving it, or making annotations on a map?  And if what you are really asking is 'how do you use Firebase?' then start with google and one of the many, many tutorials available to solve exactly that problem

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't make it so clear. I have added the data to the firebase database on their website so I have no problem with that. I just don't know how to retrieve the locations and their attitudes and longitudes and then display them all as annotations on a map. Also I am trying to make it so when you add a new location to the firebase database, it will appear next time you load the map. I have looked at a lot of tutorials but just don't know how to implement the code in to mine so I was just asking for some examples.

Comment: Please replace the images in the question with textual data of both your Firebase structure and rules. That way we don't have to retype it in an answer, it's searchable and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

In firebase get list of location using below code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;

self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
[_ref child:@"Locations"]
[_ref  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
       withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
                // Loop over children
                NSEnumerator *children = [snapshot children];
                FIRDataSnapshot *child;
                while (child = [children nextObject]) {
                  // here you can set your annotations
                  MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]
                  annotation.title = child.key
                  annotation.subtitle = @""
                  annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D (latitude: child.value[@"Latitude"], longitude: child.value[@"Latitude"])
                  [map addAnnotation:annotation]
                }
              }];
```

I am unaware of FIRDataSnapshot class so to take place name from key of child. But sure for locations key. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, is this code in objective c or swift because it just throws up a lot of errors for me. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mixed up both objective C and swift. Now code is fully in objective c

Answer (score 0):

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

do {
    try fileManager.removeItemAtPath("**Folder Name of your project**")
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
}
```

Try entering this code. It should allow you to send and recive data.